# Ansible how to iterate through multi-dimensional data

Tags: ansible

Having a loop problem. Trying to loop through the results of an aws query, to get the TargetHealth State of an ALB's target groups. It seems I need to have a nested loop structure, but can't figure it out.

The task:

```
 - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
   loop: "{{ arns.results }}"
```

The output

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg:
    TargetHealthDescriptions:
    - HealthCheckPort: '8091'
      Target:
        Id: i-00ceb9a71c24eaa5b
        Port: 8091
      TargetHealth:
        State: healthy
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => 
  msg:
    TargetHealthDescriptions:
    - HealthCheckPort: '8090'
      Target:
        Id: i-00ceb9a71c24eaa5b
        Port: 8090
      TargetHealth:
        State: healthy
```

How do I get just the 'State'?

Comment: `item.stdout` seems to be a multiline string. is the information about `status` on some other field as well perhaps? you can check if you use debug  with `var: arns.results`.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
- debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
  when: '' != ( item | regex_search( 'State: ' ) )
  with_items: "{{ arns.results.stdout_lines }}"
```

On the other hand, I'd probably try a `grep` in the command that created this output...